# How to make a beanscript function for every request

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 type script in every request now. Is it possible to make A function and B function and decide what script will use in script?

Now:

```
Request1
 |_ ScriptA
Request2
 |_ ScriptB
Request3
 |_ ScriptA
```

I want

```
Common Script A
Common Script B
Request1
 |_ Call Common Script A
Request2
 |_ Call Common Script B
Request3
 |_ Call Common Script A
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a [Post](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)/Pre processor it'll be executed after/before each request:

```
Pre/Post Processor Script
Request1
Request2
Request3
```

> Post-Processors are applied after samplers. Note that they are applied to all the samplers in the same scope,

If you use [JSR223 script](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) you can use same file name so you will write code once (DRY principle)

> Script File Name of a file to be used as a JSR223 script

Comment: Thank for your answer, In fact, I have two type script in my Jmeter file and request will use one type script. So I Think Pre/Post Processor Script can not switch script in my case

Comment: @J.SLee can you split to script per file? if not can you compile scripts to jar file ,add jar to JMeter classpath and use the method(s) inside?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve:

1. [Beanshell PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) will be executed **before** request
2. Other Beanshell Test Elements (Post-Processor, Assertion, Listener) will be executed **after** the request

   All the aforementioned Test Elements obey [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
3. If you want the "function" to act as a separate request and record the execution time into .jtl results file - go for [Beanshell Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler), you can put it under a [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and reference it in [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) to avoid code duplication
4. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it makes sense considering migration